# Strapi entry slug not auto generated from nextJs front-end

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi, headless-cms

I have a Strapi + NextJs web app that allows logged in users to post articles as authors. At the Strapi back-end and in the articles content type builder there is a slug field(UID), which is auto-generated from the article title. When I add an article at the Strapi admin back-end it works fine. However, when a logged in user POSTs an article from the front-end, the slug is not generated and the field value is set to null. Why does it happen so and what could be the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was getting the same issue with my strapi v4 app here is what I did

create a file named lifecycle.js in src/api/article/content-types/article/

in lifecycle file

```
module.exports = {
async beforeCreate(event) {
    event.params.data.slug = await strapi.service('plugin::content-manager.uid').generateUIDField({
      contentTypeUID: "api:article.article",
      field: "slug",
      data: event.params.data
    })
  }
}
```

you can change the slug name if its different or the model name